# UILabel's content size is not equal to the width anchor

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit, constraints, uilabel

I've constrained my UILabel to constant width using `NSLayoutConstraint` and `widthAnchor`, the problem is, the `contentSize` of the `UILabel` is not equal to the `widthAnchor` and in some cases is greater than what I specified.

Why is that the case? P.S. I'm a beginner to iOS Development, apologies if the answer is obvious.

Edit:
The UILabel's width was constrained to a decimal point value, which according to one user on another forum caused the UILabel to round up to the next 0.5 multiple, this caused the whole system to break. The work around for me was ceil() the width of my UILabel. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: try `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: .horizontal)`

Comment: @MohmmadS that did not work for me...

Comment: I have updated that try it again also set priority for width to 500 or 750

Comment: @MohmmadS Tried that, still not working

Comment: Could you add more details, the label full constraints ?

Comment: I'm adding constraints to CenterX and Width anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compression resistance priority here,

1. Set a lower priority for `WidthAnchor`
2. Set content compression resistance priority to 1000 for example ( higher than width anchor )

check code below.

```
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: .horizontal)
```

This [article](https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/content-hugging-and-compression-resistance-in-ios-35a0e8f19118) might be helpful in your case.

Comment: sadly, this also doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

The UILabel's width was constrained to a decimal point value, which according to one user on another forum caused the UILabel to round up to the next 0.5 multiple, this caused the whole system to break. The work around for me was ceil() the width of my UILabel. Thanks to everyone who helped.